# Content appears below left side bar instead beside it

Tags: html, css, twig

I want to create a template contain header, left sidebar, container and a footer  which are resizable  according to the width and the height of the screen.

The left sidebar contain a menu and sub menues ,my problem is that I couldn’t put the container after the left sidebar it always appear below it

***I have Updated my post according to the answers but the problem persist!***

**layout.html.twig**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {% stylesheets 'css/style.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
            {% endstylesheets %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>My header1</header>  
        <section class="sidebar-left">
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="">Forms User</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Charts</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Managment</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Add</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Delete</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Edit</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
    </section>
        <section class="content">
            {% block content %}
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
            {% endblock %}
        </section>

        <footer>My footer</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**style.css :**

```
 html, body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.sidebar-left
{
    float: left;
    width:35%;
}

/* define a fixed width for the entire menu */
.navigation {
      width:35%;
      float:left;
}

/* reset our lists to remove bullet points and padding */
.mainmenu, .submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* make ALL links (main and submenu) have padding and background color */
.mainmenu a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

/* add hover behaviour */
.mainmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #C5C5C5;
}


/* when hovering over a .mainmenu item,
  display the submenu inside it.
  we're changing the submenu's max-height from 0 to 200px;
*/

.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
}

/*
  we now overwrite the background-color for .submenu links only.
  CSS reads down the page, so code at the bottom will overwrite the code at the top.
*/

.submenu a {
  background-color: #999;
}

/* hover behaviour for links inside .submenu */
.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}

/* this is the initial state of all submenus.
  we set it to max-height: 0, and hide the overflowed content.
*/
.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.content {

    display: flex;
    width: 65%;

    /* Direction of the items, can be row or column */
    flex-direction: column;

    background-color:#0CF;
}

header{
   height: 10%;
   background-color:#D3D3D3;   
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color:#666;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
    flex: 1;
}
```

fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/naemcwsy/

this how it looks:

[image]

it should looks:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing the class `.sidebar-left` in your CSS but that element is an ID. Change `.sidebar-left` to `#sidebar-left` for your `width: 20%` to take effect. And be sure to close the opening tag for `#sidebar-left`

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}

html,
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

/* define a fixed width for the entire menu */

.sidebar-left {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}


/* reset our lists to remove bullet points and padding */

.mainmenu,
.submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/* make ALL links (main and submenu) have padding and background color */

.mainmenu a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}


/* add hover behaviour */

.mainmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #C5C5C5;
}


/* when hovering over a .mainmenu item,
  display the submenu inside it.
  we're changing the submenu's max-height from 0 to 200px;
*/

.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
}


/*
  we now overwrite the background-color for .submenu links only.
  CSS reads down the page, so code at the bottom will overwrite the code at the top.
*/

.submenu a {
  background-color: #999;
}


/* hover behaviour for links inside .submenu */

.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}


/* this is the initial state of all submenus.
  we set it to max-height: 0, and hide the overflowed content.
*/

.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  /* Direction of the items, can be row or column */
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #0CF;
}

header {
  height: 10%;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #666;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
  {% block stylesheets %} {% stylesheets 'css/style.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"> {% endstylesheets %} {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
  <header>My header1</header>
  <section class="sidebar-left">
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul class="mainmenu">
        <li><a href="">Forms User</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Charts</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Managment</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="">Add</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Delete</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Edit</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
  <section class="content">
    {% block content %}
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    {% endblock %}
  </section>

  <footer>My footer</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I have done what you have said but same problem I have updated my post

Comment: @Julie you changed the width of the sidebar to 35%, but your content is 80% wide. 80+35 = 115%, so that won't work. I changed your content to be 65% wide and that works with my answer.

Comment: you're right I changed that now and it look like the photo ( I have update what it look like now)

Comment: @Julie ok. do you still need help? I updated the code to look like your screenshot.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help  and time :)